# What is the recommended procedure for migrating 2-factor authentication to a new device?

Tags: multi-factor, iphone

A common scenario encountered with 2-factor authentication on mobile devices using, for example Google Authenticator, is migrating authentication to a new device. A natural way to accomplish this is to disable 2fa for all accounts, and then set it up again for the new device. This ensures that the old device cannot be used to generate keys, that the new device can be configured for 2fa (which would not otherwise be possible), and avoids having to store or locate additional recovery keys.

Is this procedure — disabling and re-enabling — the recommended approach? Other than the short period during which 2fa is disabled, are there other risks or drawbacks to this approach?

What is the recommended procedure for migrating 2-factor authentication to a new device?

Comment: This totally depends on the application and system you are using. I suspect you are talking of your Google account. But if you are using other applications/systems you might be able to enroll a second authentication device. Now the user could either authenticate with the old one or the new one. Then you can disable or decomission the old one.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that disabling 2FA entirely is a recommendable approach, but this update process is specific to the site/service implementing 2FA.

In the case of Google 2FA, I don't think disabling it is required, or even recommendable, if only for the practical implications.[1]

**To migrate Google Two Factor Authentication to a new device**, I'd recommend the following:

- Make sure to have generated and saved/printed a set of emergency codes, in case anything goes wrong. You can also register a phone number to send codes to.[2]
- Configure a new Authenticator app via your account preferences, using your old device to log in, and configuring Authenticator on the new one.[3]

---

If you are reinitializing the device that has Authenticator installed, you could do one of the following:

- Login before wiping the old device, re-install and update the Authenticator prefs in your account, or
- Use one of the aforementionned emergency codes to log in and update your prefs once the device is re-installed.

---

<sub>**1**: If you have set up app-specific passwords (e-mail client on your phone or computer, for example), they won't be able to connect while 2FA is turned off, and you may need to reconfigure all of them once you switch it back on.</sub>
  <sub>**2**: This will also prevent any catastrophic scenarios where a phone is lost along with its backups</sub>
  <sub>**3**: As far as I am aware of, Google 2FA does not allow you to have two Authenticator app's configured for your account. Once the new one is succesfully set up, the old one won't work.</sub>

Comment: Indeed, this appears (now that I've done it) to be very service-specific. But most services support multiple forms of mfa, so it is possible to leave mfa enabled using a different channel (e.g., phone or e-mail), during migration.